# Pass a SASS variable to a Vue component property

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm still very new to frontend development, and I'm working on a small Vue component that is basically a Vuetify card with a colored border on one side. The color is a property of the component. This works so far:

```html
<template>
  <v-card :style="borderColorStyle">
    <slot></slot>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    color: {
      required: false,
      type: String as PropType<string>,
      default: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    borderColorStyle () {
      if (this.color) {
        return `border-left: 5px solid ${this.color}`
      } else {
        return ''
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
  @import '@/sass/variables.sass'
  .v-card
    height: 100%
    border-left: 5px solid $my__darkgray
</style>
```

As you can see, we use SASS, and we used it to define a number of colors.

Now, how can I use these SASS definitions to set the color when using this component?

For example, if my variables.sass contains

```
$my_coolgreen: #288970
```

is there any way I can do something like this?

```
<StatusCard color="my_coolgreen">
  Some text
</StatusCard>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Via classes

While you can't pass a Sass variable through a prop to your styles in Vue 2, you could apply a CSS class that uses the Sass variable. For example, this template uses [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) to conditionally apply `.myClass` based on the value of `color`:

```html
<template>
  <v-card :class="{ myClass: color === '$my_coolgreen' }">
  </v-card>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '@/sass/variables.sass'
  .myClass
    border-left: 5px solid $my_coolgreen
</style>
```

#### Vue 3 `<style vars>`

Vue 3's [`<style vars>`](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/sfc-improvements/active-rfcs/0000-sfc-style-variables.md) (still experimental) allows using props as [*CSS custom properties*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) inside the style block, as shown in the example below. However, Vuetify 2 currently does not support Vue 3.

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped vars="{ color }">
  @import '@/sass/variables.sass'
  .v-card
    border-left: 5px solid var(--color)
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we ended up doing:

```html
<template>
    <v-card :class="['pa-2','my__status__card', color]" style="background-color: white !important">
      <slot></slot>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    color: {
      required: false,
      type: String as PropType<string>,
      default: 'info'
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style lang="sass">
  .v-card
    height: 100%

  .my__status__card
    border-style: solid !important
    border-left-width: 5px !important
    border-top-width: 0px !important
    border-bottom-width: 0px !important
    border-right-width: 0px !important
</style>
```

So we give the card a style that removes all borders except the left one.
The color property only works with theme colors. So this might not be a solution that makes sense for everyone, but it's what we needed.